What kind of Fibonacci subword at this offset?
When in the Fibonacci number recurrence fn+2=fn+fn+1 one replaces the "+" with string concatenation one will get the sequence of  Fibonacci words. If we start with F0=a and F1=b, then the first few elements will be a,b,ab,bab,abbab,bababbab,abbabbababbab,... etc.
If N>1 and n<N then Fn will naturally occur as a substring in FN:
For example, if n=3 and N=6, Then F4, by construction, contains a copy of F3 at its end. F5, being the concatenation of F3 and F4, therefore contains two copies, and F6 three copies, one from F4 and two from F5.
We can find these copies at offsets 2,5 and 10:
a
b
ab
bab
-->
abbab
  -->
bababbab
-->  -->
abbabbababbab
  -->-->  -->

But, we cannot rule out more occurrences, for example, there is one at offset 7 that is not directly explained by the recursion formula:
abbabbababbab
       ***   

We'll call such occurrences "strange" as opposed to the "regular" occurrences above.
Task:
Given N>n and offset o your program or function must return one out of three consistent values indicating whether Fn occurs in FN at offset o and if so which kind of occurrence it is.
Test cases:
N         n         o             answer
------------------------------------------
4         0         0             regular
4         0         1             wrong
4         0         2             wrong
4         0         3             regular
4         0         4             wrong
5         0         0             wrong
5         0         1             regular
5         0         2             wrong
5         0         3             regular
5         0         4             wrong
5         0         5             wrong
5         0         6             regular
5         0         7             wrong
4         1         0             wrong
4         1         1             regular
4         1         2             regular
4         1         3             wrong
4         1         4             regular
5         1         0             regular
5         1         1             wrong
5         1         2             regular
5         1         3             wrong
5         1         4             regular
5         1         5             regular
5         1         6             wrong
5         1         7             regular
1         0         0             wrong
10        2         7             wrong
7         3         0             regular
7         3         7             strange
7         3         9             wrong
7         3         10            regular
7         3         11            wrong
14        7         47            strange
14        7         479           strange
14        7         335           strange
14        7         335           strange
14        7         369           strange
14        7         513           strange
14        7         100           wrong
14        7         200           wrong
14        7         300           wrong
14        7         13            regular
14        7         123           regular
14        7         233           regular
14        7         322           regular

If you need even more test cases here is the Python script that generated the above.
Inspired by this puzzling SE post:
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/122866/71595

Suggested edge case: 2 0 0 (or anything else with $n=0$).

($n=1$ may also be problematic)

@Arnauld Eugh, give me a moment to fix my reference code.

JavaScript (ES6), 113 bytes
Expects (N)(n)(o) and returns false for strange, true for regular, 2 for wrong.
N=>n=>g=(o,x,y=(U="toUpperCase")[+!x])=>~N--?g(o,n--?y:y=p=y[U](),x&&x+y):(s=x.substr(o,p.length))[U]()==p?s==p:2

Try it online!
Method
We recursively build all patterns \$F_0\$ to \$F_N\$ using letters in lower case (ironically using the 'o' and 't' from the string 'toUpperCase' for golfing reasons).
When \$F_n\$ is reached, we convert it to upper case, save it in \$p\$ and use the transformed string for the recursion. All subsequent regular occurrences of \$p\$ will therefore appear in upper case as well.
At the end of the process, we look for \$p\$ at offset \$o\$ in \$F_N\$:

If \$p\$ appears in upper case, this is a regular match.
If \$p\$ appears in lower or mixed case, this is a strange match.
If \$p\$ doesn't appear at all, this is obviously wrong.

Commented
N => n =>             // outer functions taking N and n
g = (                 // inner recursive function taking:
  o,                  //   the offset o
  x,                  //   a string x (initially undefined)
  y = (               //   a string y initialized by using the
    U = "toUpperCase" //   first 2 characters of "toUpperCase":
  )[+!x]              //   - "o" if x is undefined (1st iteration)
                      //   - "t" if x is defined (2nd iteration)
) =>                  //
~N-- ?                // if N != -1 (decrement afterwards):
  g(                  //   do a recursive call:
    o,                //     pass o unchanged
    n-- ?             //     if n != 0 (decrement afterwards):
      y               //       use y unchanged
    :                 //     else:
      y = p = y[U](), //       update y and p to y in upper case
    x && x + y        //     if x is defined, pass x + y
                      //     (pass undefined otherwise)
  )                   //   end of recursive call
:                     // else:
  (                   //
    s = x.substr(     //   s = relevant slice of x
      o, p.length     //       at offset o and of size p.length
    )                 //
  )[U]() == p ?       //   if s in upper case is equal to p:
    s == p            //     compare s with p (Boolean value)
  :                   //   else:
    2                 //     return 2 for 'wrong'


Charcoal, 75 bytes
ＮθＮηＮζＦab⊞υιＦθ⊞υ⭆²§υ⁻λ²Ｉ∧№⌕Ａ§υθ§υηζ⊕∨‹η²№Ｅ⌕Ａ§υ⊕⁻θηbΣＥ²×№…§υ⊕⁻θηι§υλＬ§υ⁻η¬λζ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs 0 for wrong, 1 for strange and 2 for regular. Explanation:
ＮθＮηＮζ

Input N, n and o.
Ｆab⊞υιＦθ⊞υ⭆²§υ⁻λ²

Generate the first N+2 Fibonacci words.
Ｉ∧№⌕Ａ§υθ§υηζ

If o is not one of the places where the nth word appears in the Nth word, then the output is 0.
⊕∨‹η²

If n<2 then the output is 2.
№Ｅ⌕Ａ§υ⊕⁻θηbΣＥ²×№…§υ⊕⁻θηι§υλＬ§υ⁻η¬λζ

Otherwise, the Nth word is composed of copies of the n-1th and nth words, given by the N-n+1th word, where an a in that word represents a copy of the n-1th word and a b in that word represents a copy of the nth word. Using the lengths of the n-1th and nth words, generate the offsets inside the Nth word corresponding to all of the bs which represent all of the regular nth subwords, and check whether o is one of those.

JavaScript (Node.js), 99 bytes
(N,n,o)=>[0,n].map(k=>(F=n=>('ab'[n]||F(n-2)+F(n-1)).replace(/./,n-k&&'$&'))(N).indexOf(F(n),o)==o)

Try it online!
Output [true,true] for regular, [true,false] for strange, [false,false] for wrong.

Let's denote \$x\#y\$ as string concatenation, and \$x\left[1:\right]\$ as string slicing which remove the first letter from \$x\$.
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
\textbf{a}&x=0\\
\textbf{b}&x=1\\
F(x-2)\#F(x-1)&x>1
\end{cases}
$$
$$
G(x)=\begin{cases}
F(x)&x\le 1\wedge x\ne n\\
G(x-2)\#G(x-1)&x>1\wedge x\ne n\\
\textbf{c}\#F(x)\left[1:\right]&x=n
\end{cases}
$$

Define \$F(x)\$ as described in this question, Build \$F(N)\$ and \$F(n)\$ to verify if \$F(n)\$ matches \$F(N)\$ at position \$o\$.
Define \$G(x)\$, it replace first letter of \$F(n)\$ by a third letter, while keeping other rules of \$F\$. Build \$G(N)\$ and \$G(n)\$ to verify if \$G(n)\$ matches \$G(N)\$ at position \$o\$.
We collect above 2 values as an array and return it.

I have no idea how to prove its correctness, it simply passed all testcases. Any prove or bad cases are welcomed.

That's fairly similar to my reference implementation. I'd argue that it's correct in principle is kind of obvious, no?

05AB1E, 30 bytes
1ÝλN¹›i‚»ë«]¹I‚è`IF¦¶Û}Dþ‚sδÅ?

Inputs in the order \$n,N,o\$. Outputs [1,1] for regular; [0,1] for strange; and [0,0] for wrong.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
  λ        # Create a recursive environment,
           # to output the infinite sequence
1Ý         # Starting with a(0)=0 and a(1)=1
           # Where every following a(x) is calculated as:
           #  (implicitly push the previous terms a(x-2) and a(x-1))
   N¹›i    #  If x is larger than first input `n`:
       ‚   #   Pair the two previous terms: [a(x-2),a(x-1)]
        »  #   Join this pair with newline-delimiter
      ë    #  Else:
       «   #   Append term a(x-1) to a(x-2) instead
  ]        # Close both the if-statement and recursive environment
   ¹I‚     # Push a pair of the first two inputs: [n,N]
      è    # (0-based) index those into the infinite list
`          # Pop and push both separated to the stack
 IF        # Loop the third input `o` amount of times:
   ¦       #  Remove the first bit
    ¶Û     #  And also trim a potential leading newline character
  }D       # After the loop: duplicate the off-set result
    þ      # Remove all newlines from the copy, by only keeping digits
     ‚     # Pair the two together
       δ   # Map over this pair:
      s Å? #  Check for both whether it starts with the n'th term
           # (after which this pair is output implicitly as result)


FYI, I've fixed my code for $n<2$ at the cost of +6 bytes.

@Arnauld Thanks for the heads up, but with the way my recursive method is build up, a straight-forward fix seems to be 8 bytes (¹„abD²èu©²ǝSλè«N²Qiu©]³.$Du‚®δÅ?). Can probably be golfed a bit to 6-7, but that would still tie it with my current approach, so I'll just leave it as is.

Feels weird to see an IF in 05AB1E...

Python3, 356 bytes
I=lambda a:isinstance(a,str)
T=lambda a:a if I(a)else''.join(T(b)for _,b in a)
def O(t,n,C):
 if I(t):return
 for a,b in t:
  if a==n:yield C[0]
  if I(b):C[0]+=len(b)
  else:yield from O(b,n,C)
def f(N,n,o):
 k=[(0,'a'),(t:=1,'b')]
 while(t:=t+1)<=N:k+=[(t,k[-2:])]
 K=dict(k)
 if o in[*O(K[N],n,[0])]:return 2
 if T(K[N])[o:].startswith(T(K[n])):return 1

Try it online!
